# Check if Javascript is enabled and display a message if it is not using an asp custom control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, dom-events, asp.net-ajax

I'm using Javascript, ASP.net and C#.
I want to write a custom control to check if Javascript is enabled on the browser and display a message.
I'm using the following approach:

- the control shows a message "Javascript disable" in a `<div>` tag
- the control adds in the  section a Javascript section with this line:

  ```
  window.onload = function() {{document.getElementById('My_MESSAGE_DIV').style.display = 'none';}}
  ```

The problem is the following:
when Javascipt is enabled the `onload` event is fired when the page is already displayed so the message "Javascript disable" appears on the page and disappear immediately, I would like to avoid this!
Any suggestion?

Possible solution:

- find an event that get fired before the document is displayed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Um, how about the [noscript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1) tag to display your message? Doesn't always have to be that complex.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for annakata's answer. Alternatively - if you want to choose the complex way ;) - where you don't want to just display a message but provide alternative behavior in case of the presence/absence of JavaScript I do something like having two kind of containers (divs, Panels or simple labels for msgs), where the container providing JavaScript functionality is hidden with CSS tags (i.e. display:none). Then I render a JavaScript which on startup will remove the "display:none" from the JavaScript enabled part and add it to the non-javascript part. If JavaScript should not be present, obviously just the non-javascript part will be shown.

I hope I was able to explain myself. But as I mentioned, for simple messages the noscript tag is always preferable. Always strive for the simplest solution;